# How to position two text fields with margins in one line?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position two input fields in one line, by applying the `float: left;` property in an `.inline` class.

However, because all `input[type="text"]` have a `margin: 5px;`, it will only work with `width: 50%` only if I remove the margins.

With margin of 5:

[image: Image 1]

Without any margin:

[image]

What would be an ideal solution?

Here's a codepen link: http://codepen.io/biskotaki/pen/YXdYYE?editors=110

Comment: reduce the width of your textboxes to account for the margins

Comment: How can I do that automatically though?

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdwMpE?editors=110

Comment: That would probably be something like `width:calc(50% - 10px)`, which is ugly...

Comment: through css!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Of course, but that's why I asked for a solution.

Comment: There, I just upvoted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
input[type="text"]
{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}

.inline input {
  float: left;
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
  margin:5px;
}
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/fL0gm3h9/

Comment: Thanks a lot, can you send me another fiddle on how I can have more than two fields in one line using that way?

Answer (score 2):

Reduce width to 48%

```css
input[type="text"]
{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}

.inline input {
  float: left;
  width: 48%;
  margin:5px;}
```

```html
<div class="inline">
  <input type="text" placeholder="text 1">
  <input type="text" placeholder="text 2">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have a `.inline` class, consider adding this:

```
.inline>input[type="text"] {margin:0}
```

This will disable the margin on the appropriate input boxes.